# Perl syntax errors

Tags: perl

I am trying to find the syntax error, but I can't.

**Error message:**

```
syntax error at /Users/MMM/Desktop/extract2.pl line 52, near "$dbm{"
syntax error at /Users/MMM/Desktop/extract2.pl line 57, near "}"
Execution of /Users/MMM/Desktop/extract2.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

**Code:** (error line marked)

```
#!/usr/bin/Perl
#Extract the accession number and#!/usr /bin/perl
#Extract the accession number and the sequence section from the records in the GenBank file
#Excellence is an Endeavor of Persistence. Chance Favors a Prepared Mind

#use warnings;
use BeginPerlBioinfo;
use strict;

# Declare and initialize variables
my $fh;
my $record;
my $dna;
my $annotation;
my $fields;
my $dbm = ' ';
my $answer;
my $offset;
my $LSU = '/Users/MMM/Desktop/FUNGUS/LSU.gb';

# open DBM file, creating if neccessary
unless (dbmopen(my %dbm, 'GB' , 0644)) {
    print "Cannot open DBM file GB with mode 0644\n";
    exit;
}

#Parse GenBank library, saving accession number and sequence in DBM file

$fh = open_file($LSU);

$offset = tell ($fh);

while ( $record = get_next_record($fh))   {
    #Get accession field for this record.

    ($annotation, $dna) = get_annotation_and_dna($record);

    my %fields = parse_annotation( $annotation);

    my $accession =  $fields { 'ACCESSION'};

    # extract just the accession number and sequence from the accession field
    #-- remove any trailing spaces
    $accession =~ s/^ACCESSION\s*//;

    $accession =~ s/\s*$//;

    #store the key value of accession/offset

    my $dbm{$accession} = $offset; # <--- ERROR

    #get offset for the next record

    $offset = tell($fh);
}
```

Comment: it would be easier to find syntax errors if your code was indented uniformly.

Comment: `my $dbm = ' ';`, `dbmopen(my %dbm, 'GB' , 0644)`, `my dbm{$accession} = $offset;` `print join ("\n", my %dbm), "\n";` are you sure you want to declare `dbm` in all these ways? `my` is used to declare a variable.

Comment: @Matt: The code in the original post is fair, except that the scope of `%dbm` is confied to the `unless` block. Presumably `my dbm{$accession}` is an attempt to fix that

Comment: @Borodin `$dbm` was unused and `print join ("\n", my %dbm), "\n";` wasn't going to print anything.

Comment: @Matt: Sure, but you majored on *"are you sure you want to declare dbm in all these ways"*, and I think it was the wrong focus

Comment: @user3780167: There are many problems with your code, so you have started a minor *"which bug is the most important"* war! It looks like you have written the entire program before testing anything, and that is a frustrating way to work because you will start with a huge list of errors and little idea where the problem lies. Write your code incrementally, and test often enough that you know *exactly* which amendment caused an error. With Perl it's far from arduous to do things that way as you have to wait only a few seconds to see the result. And as `Hunter McMillen` says, indent your code!

Answer (score 6):

`my $dbm{$accession}` is invalid syntax; `my` can only be used with a variable, not a hash or array subscript.  There isn't even any need to use `my` with a subscript; just write `$dbm{$accession} = $offset;`.

Comment: `my $dbm{$accession}` is a syntax error, and clearly a mistake here. But `local $dbm{$accession}` works fine,  and it can be useful to assign a temporary value to a hash (or array) element

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with lexical scope of the dbm hash.

you open it , but it was only declared in that scope. then you declare it again on line 52.

When you initialize variables you have

```
my $dbm = '  ';
```

which should be

```
my %dbm;
```

everywhere else you use %dbm : **you don't need to re-declare it as 'my'**, this should get rid of the error.

Comment: no, there is no scoping problem here, and there is a my %dbm already, and it's fine to have a scalar and hash with the same name.

Comment: no, actually, they aren't; they declare it once and are trying to declare a hash element many times (which isn't allowed and gives their syntax error)

Comment: so we are both right, they declare a subset of the dbm hash, when they were just trying to assign it a value.